# Applying a function over consecutive pairs of list elements in R without loops

Tags: r, vectorization, igraph

I am trying to find an efficient (i.e. avoid using loops) way to apply a function that iteratively takes as arguments the current and previous (or next) elements of a list and returns a lists of the result (the length of which will necessarily be 1 element shorter).
As a concrete example,

I have a list of vertices defining a path in some graph

```
vlist <- c(1,2,7,12,17)
```

which come from a lattice graph constructed using the igraph function "lattice"

```
G <- graph.lattice(c(5,7))
```

I want to apply the function "get.edge.ids" over vlist so that the list returned yields the ids of the edges connecting the consecutive elements in vlist.
E.g. I want the ids of edges 1-->2, 2-->7, 7-->12, 12-->17

This is trivial using a for loop,

```
    findEids <- function(G,vlist) {
        outlist=c()
        for (i in 1:(length(vlist)-1) {
            outlist=append(outlist,get.edge.ids(G,c(vlist[i],vlist[i+1])))
        }
        return(outlist)
    }
```

but I would like to use a vectorized approach like apply() or reduce() to see if I can get it to work more quickly since I will need to call functions like this repeatedly from a script (for example, to compute the total stretch for a spanning tree of G).

Comment: If you want a list, `sapply` and `lapply` might work.  `lapply` will always return a list, and with `sapply` it depends on the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `mapply` for that. For example

```
a<-1:1000
mapply(function(x,y)x-y,a[-1000],a[-1])
```

It appears to be slightly faster than the for loop version:

```
> f <- function(x,y)x-y
> g <- function(){
     o<-c();
     for(i in a[-1000])o<-c(o,f(i,i+1))
> }


>
> system.time( 
+     for(i in 1:1000){
+         mapply(f,a[-1000],a[-1])
+     }
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
  2.344   0.000   2.345 


> system.time(for(i in 1:1000)g())
   user  system elapsed 
  3.399   0.000   3.425
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
library(zoo)

findEids <- function(gr, v.list) {
  rollapply(v.list, width=2, FUN=function(x) {
    get.edge.ids(gr, x)
  })
}

findEids(G, vlist)
## [1]  1  4 13 22
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually, for this specific question, you can query the whole path at once with

```
as.vector(E(G, path=vlist))
# [1]  1  4 13 22
```

This is very readable, and seems to be faster than any other solution, although speed probably only matters if you have long paths.

```
v2 <- c(1,2,7,12,17,12,7,2)
vlist <- rep(v2, 100000)

system.time(get.edge.ids(G, vlist[c(1, rep(2:(length(vlist) - 1), each = 2), 
                                  length(vlist))]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.218   0.014   0.232 

system.time(as.vector(E(G, path=vlist)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.028   0.007   0.035
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is not direct answer to the question in the subject but more specific to your request

If you look at description of argument `vp` in function `get.edge.ids` you will se that

> **vp**
>   The indicent vertices, given as vertex ids or symbolic vertex
>   names. *They are interpreted pairwise, i.e. the first and second are
>   used for the first edge, the third and fourth for the second, etc.*

So in this case all you need is that you create a new vector from `vlist` such that all elements except first and last, are repeated twice. You can do that by using `vlist[c(1, rep(2:(length(vlist)-1), each = 2), length(vlist))]`

```
c(1, rep(2:(length(vlist) - 1), each = 2), length(vlist))
## [1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
vlist[c(1, rep(2:(length(vlist) - 1), each = 2), length(vlist))]
## [1]  1  2  2  7  7 12 12 17


get.edge.ids(G, vlist[c(1, rep(2:(length(vlist) - 1), each = 2), length(vlist))])
## [1]  1  4 13 22
```

Comment: Interesting. This looks very promising. If I need to modify this to skip over regular intervals (rather than just consecutive pairs) would I just modify the "each = 2" to "each = interval"? If so, then this should work perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned to use dplyr, which can solve this via mutate / transmute and paste:

```
data.frame(x=vlist) %>% 
mutate(y=lead(x)) %>%
transmute(edge=paste(x,y,sep="-->")
```

which yields

```
     edge
1   1-->2
2   2-->7
3  7-->12
4 12-->17
5 17-->NA
```