# Apply function over every two consecutive list elements

Tags: r, mapply

I wonder if there is a more efficient way of applying a function over every two consecutive elements of a list. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622209/for-loop-on-a-list-of-matrix-and-the-mean-of-all-the-matrix-in-r) got me thinking, and the solution I posted for the user came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799674/applying-a-function-over-consecutive-pairs-of-list-elements-in-r-without-loops).

I think it is decent enough to use `Map/mapply` with `somelist[-length(somelist)]` and `somelist[-1]` as the arguments to a `function(x, y)` call, but is there any direct approach, maybe implemented in one of the bigger/newer packages?

Consider this example (stolen from the aforementioned question):

I've got a list of three matrices:

```
set.seed(1)
matlist <- list(M1 = matrix(sample(1:10, 4, replace = T), nrow = 2, ncol = 2),
                M2 = matrix(sample(1:10, 4, replace = T), nrow = 2, ncol = 2),
                M3 = matrix(sample(1:10, 4, replace = T), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
                )
```

and now I want to calculate `M1+M2` and `M2+M3`. The mentioned approach would be

```
Map(`+`, matlist[-3], matlist[-1])

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5   11
[2,]   11   15

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   12   13
[2,]    5   18
```

Is there any variant of the `apply` family to which I would just feed

```
xapply(matlist, `+`)
```

I know I could just write that myself as a little helper, like

```
xapply <- function(x, FUN){
  Map(FUN, x[-length(x)], x[-1])
}
```

but as far as I understood [this classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized), `sapply/lapply` and so on gain their performance advantage over `for` loops by utilizing `C` code, therefore the `xapply` function above would be convenience only, not boosting performance.

Comment: what is the problem with the function you created.  There won't be much performance advantage with a properly written `for` and `sapply/lapply`

Comment: There's no problem with it per se, I was just wondering if this way of looping over `x` and `x+1` was already implemented in any kind of optimized fashion.

Comment: Note that `Map` belongs to the `apply` family already, just calling `mapply`

Comment: Yeah, I just used `Map` to avoid the default `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that the apply function are faster than looping. Sometimes they are not.

If the idea is not to use indexes but to use the whole object approach then here are some approaches although the `Map` approach in the question seems better.

**1) matrix** `rollsum` will perform a sum over windows. It does not work with lists but if you write conversion functions to and from matrix it would work:

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

# convert between list and matrix where each row of matrix is one list component
list2mat <- function(x) t(sapply(x, c))
mat2list <- function(x, n) lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) matrix(x[i, ], n))

nr <- nrow(matlist[[1]])
matlist %>% list2mat %>% rollsum(2) %>% mat2list(nr)
```

**2) Reduce** This is an attempt with `Reduce`:

```
ans <- list()
invisible(Reduce(function(x, y) { ans <<- c(ans, list(x + y)); y }, matlist))
```

**3) array** Another approach is to work with 3d arrays rather than lists.  This gives rise to a compact one-liner using `aaply` and `rollsum`.

We first convert the list to a 3d array using `simplify2array` giving array `a` and now within that framework:

```
library(plyr)
library(zoo)

a <- simplify2array(matlist) # convert matlist to array

aa <- aaply(a, 1:2, rollsum, 2)

# check
bb <- simplify2array(Map("+", matlist[-1], matlist[-3]))
identical(unname(aa), unname(bb))
## [1] TRUE
```

`aaply` is basically an idempotent apply and we could do this with ordinary `apply` if we were willing to permute (i.e. generalized transpose)
the 3d array.  That is this is the same as the `aaply` line above:

```
library(magrittr)
aa <- a %<% apply(1:2, rollsum, 2) %>% aperm(c(2, 3, 1))
```

This would also work:

```
aa <- a %>% aperm(3:1) %>% apply(2:3, rollsum, 2) %>% aperm(3:1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this is a great overview of possible solutions!

Answer (score 0):

1. Here's one slightly different approach, although I don't like it much.

   ```
    purr::map(seq_along(matlist)[-length(matlist)], 
          ~ reduce(list(matlist[[.]], matlist[[.+1]]), `+`))
   ```
2. Here's a variant with the pipe, which I think is better, just because I like the pipe.

   ```
   matlist %>% 
      list(a = .[-length(.)], b = .[-1]) %>%
      .[-1] %>% 
      pmap( ~ .x + .y)
   ```
3. Unfortunately like the original Map answer, that gives a list with erroneous names. To get rid of the erroneous names you'd have to do:

   ```
   matlist %>% 
       list(a = .[-length(.)], b = .[-1]) %>% 
       .[-1] %>% 
       modify_depth(1, unname)  %>% 
       pmap( ~ .x + .y)
   ```

I think it's worth it to get rid of the names, since they're misleading.